# I am able to login even if I enter wrong password

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication

The register route is working perfectly but in the login route after I press login button it logs in even if the password is wrong

Code of app.js is

```
const express=require("express");
const bodyParser=require("body-parser");
const mongoose=require("mongoose");
const bcrypt=require("bcryptjs");
const ejs=require("ejs");
const passport = require("passport");
const session = require("express-session");
const passportLocalMongoose=require("passport-local-mongoose")
const findOrCreate = require("mongoose-findorcreate")
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;

const app=express();

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
//app.set("view engine","ejs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(session({
    secret: "Our little secret.",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
  }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.json());
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/userDB",{useNewUrlParser:true});
var name;
var temp_email;
const UserSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
});
const DataSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    email:String,
    name:String,
    weight:Number,
    dob:Number
})
UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
UserSchema.plugin(findOrCreate);
DataSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
DataSchema.plugin(findOrCreate);
const user=new mongoose.model("user",UserSchema);
const data=new mongoose.model("data",DataSchema);

passport.serializeUser(function(user,done){
  done(null,user.id);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function(id,done){
  user.findById(id,function(err,user){
    done(err,user);
  });
});

app.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.render("index.ejs");
});
app.get("/login",function(req,res){
    res.render("login.ejs");
});
app.get("/error-login",function(req,res){
    res.render("error-login.ejs");
});
app.get("/error-register",function(req,res){
    res.render("error-register.ejs");
});
app.get("/success",function(req,res){
    res.render("success.ejs");
});
app.get("/register",function(req,res){
    res.render("register.ejs");
});
app.get("/details",function(req,res){
    res.render("details.ejs");
});
app.post("/login",function(req,res){
    const newuser= new user({
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
    });
    req.login(newuser,function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            // res.redirect("error-login");
        }
        else{
            passport.authenticate("local")(req,res,function(){
                res.redirect("/success")
            });
            data.find({email: req.body.username},function(err,User_name){
                if(User_name===undefined){
                    res.render("error-login")
                }
                else{
                        console.log(User_name[0])
                        name=User_name[0].name
                        console.log(name)
                    
                }
                
            }) 
        }   
    })
    
});
app.post("/register",function(req,res){
    user.register({
        username: req.body.username,
    },req.body.password,function(err,user){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            console.log("Error");
            res.redirect("error-register");
        }
        else{
            passport.authenticate("local")(req,res,function(){
                res.redirect("details")
            })
            temp_email=req.body.username
        }
    })
    // data.create({
    //     email:req.body.username,
    //     name:req.body.name
    // },function(err,user){
    //     if(err){
    //         console.log(err);
    //     }
    //     else{
    //         console.log(user);
    //     }
    // })
    // name=req.body.name
    // console.log(name)

})
app.post("/details",function(req,res){
    data.create({
        email: temp_email,
        name:req.body.name,
        weight:req.body.weight,
        dob:req.body.DOB
    })
    name=req.body.name
    console.log(name)
    res.redirect("success")
})
app.listen(3000,function()
{
    console.log("Server started");
});
```

code of login.ejs is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>login</h1>
    <form action="/login" method="POST">
      <div>
        <input type="email" name="username">
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="password" name="password">
      </div>
      <button type="submit">login</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

code for register.ejs is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>register</h1>
    <form class="" action="/register" method="POST">
      <div>
        <input type="email" name="username">
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="password" name="password">
      </div>
      <!-- <div>
        <input type="text" name="name">
      </div> -->
      <button type="submit">register</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

So please help me solve the issue. When I register it is showing in mongodb and also it is getting redirected to success page, but during login even if I enter the wrong password it is logging in.